# Merging values contained by key in a map (Java)

Tags: java, guava

```
final Multimap<String, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>[] actionMap = new Multimap[]{null};
final boolean[] loaded = {false};

db.execute(connection -> {
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    actionMap[0] = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("Blah Blah...
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            final String name = ...

            actionMap[0].put(name, new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(int1, int2));
```

I have a map where I use `SimpleEntry` to insert two integer values (int1, int2). On a duplicate key I want to merge values of what's already mapped. My idea is `computeIfPresent` but I have no idea of the BiFunctions since I'm using `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` to enter the two values. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you referring to this [Multimap](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)?

Comment: Yeah that’s it.

Answer (score 1):

Before you put and overwrite, retrieve the existing value.

- If you get null, there is no such value and you put as initially intended.
- If you get something, merge your new data into something.

Answer (score 0):

Based on input you gave (which could be more complete) it seems that you're trying to use wrong structure for your data. Assuming you want to merge **value of the entry if both `name` and `int1` exist**, you should use Guava's Table instead. Let's consider this piece of code as an idea:

```
@Test
public void shouldMergeValues() throws SQLException {
    given(resultSet.getString("name"))
            .willReturn("name")
            .willReturn("name")
            .willReturn("name")
            .willReturn("name2");
    given(resultSet.getInt("key"))
            .willReturn(1)
            .willReturn(1)
            .willReturn(2)
            .willReturn(100);
    given(resultSet.getInt("value"))
            .willReturn(2)
            .willReturn(40)
            .willReturn(3)
            .willReturn(200);
    given(resultSet.next())
            .willReturn(true)
            .willReturn(true)
            .willReturn(true)
            .willReturn(true)
            .willReturn(false);

    Table<String, Integer, Integer> actionTable = HashBasedTable.create();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String name = resultSet.getString("name");
        int int1 = resultSet.getInt("key");
        int int2 = resultSet.getInt("value");
        if (actionTable.contains(name, int1)) {
            Integer oldInt2 = actionTable.get(name, int1);
            actionTable.put(name, int1, oldInt2 + int2); // in this example "+" is the "merge" function
        } else {
            actionTable.put(name, int1, int2);
        }
    }

    assertThat(actionTable) // {name={1=42, 2=3}, name2={100=200}}
            .containsCell("name", 1, 42)
            .containsCell("name", 2, 3)
            .containsCell("name2", 100, 200)
            .hasSize(3);
}
```

Given 4 rows: `("name", 1, 2)`, `("name", 1, 40)`, `("name", 2, 3)` and `("name2", 100, 200)` and example "merge" operation being addition, you'd get Table `{name={1=42, 2=3}, name2={100=200}}`. Please check if it fits your use case.